# Jquery and chrome issue

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I have the following jquery code which works fine in firefox and safari but not in chrome.

Basically I just want the following code to run when the page loads:

```
$("ul#menu-master_menu li ul li a span.sf-sub-indicator:first-child").remove();
```

For some reason I can't get this to work so I have set it up to run on an image load as below:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $("#logoLoader").load(function(){
        $("ul#menu-master_menu li ul li a span.sf-sub-indicator:first-child").remove();
    }).attr('src', 'http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/volumes/images/logo.png');
});
```

This does not work in chrome. Can anyone please offer me a solution or explanation as to why it does not work in chrome. As I mentioned I just require this line of code to run:

```
$("ul#menu-master_menu li ul li a span.sf-sub-indicator:first-child").remove();
```

Thanks

Comment: show your html or make a fiddle

Comment: What version of Chrome?

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using `.ready`: http://api.jquery.com/ready/ ?

Comment: Does it work in other browsers?

Answer (score 0):

*I'm going to post this here, allthough this would be a comment. I write this here to explain debugging in this situation, which I cant in a comment-box*

You want to debug your selector. If you are sure the problem lies in this line, you want to debug it. We can try to see if it is the selector, and complicate it down down the run:

```
// In the $(document).ready(); :
console.log( $("ul#menu-master_menu").length );
console.log( $("ul#menu-master_menu").length );
console.log( $("ul#menu-master_menu li").length );
console.log( $("ul#menu-master_menu li ul").length );
console.log( $("ul#menu-master_menu li ul li").length );
console.log( $("ul#menu-master_menu li ul li a").length );
console.log( $("ul#menu-master_menu li ul li a span").length );
console.log( $("ul#menu-master_menu li ul li a span.sf-sub-indicator").length );
console.log( $("ul#menu-master_menu li ul li a span.sf-sub-indicator:first-child").length );
```

That should give you 9 log-items in your debugger. If not, find out where it fails.
If it does work all 9 lines, switch the `.remove()` to `.css({background:'pink'})` to see if it selects the right element.

Answer (score 0):

This line fire the event after the page has finished loading

```
$(window).load(function() {
```

That's way the following function is not triggering

> $("#logoLoader").load(function(){});

Try change the `$(window).load( function() {})` to `$( document ).ready( function() { ... })`

Comment: That completely depends on context. The window.load can be in a doc.ready. Maybe this code needs to get triggered when the page is done loading :)

Comment: Ok, so he can remove the unnecessary #logoLoader load event, since it's already loaded